# Visual Studio 2013 to build on TFS 2010 - Build Issues

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Fellow Admin and Developers.   We have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 and we have built a .NET Framework 4.5 ASP.NET MVC application

Please note I have installed .NET Framework 4.5.1 on the TFS Build Server 2010 - Registry = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > NET FRAMWORK SETUP > NDP > v4 > Client > 1033 > Version = 4.5.50938

I have copied the directories
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
 - Web
 - WebApplications

However I am still getting the following Errors and Warnings when attempting a build.

```
Errors
Filters\AjaxOnly.cs (16): The type or namespace name 'ActionMethodSelectorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (511): The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (508): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (31): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (30): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (122): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (121): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (207): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (509): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (206): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (298): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (373): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (375): The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (372): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (481): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (483): The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (480): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrapHelpers.cs (299): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (397): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (400): The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (398): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Filters\HandleModelStateExceptionAttribute.cs (14): The type or namespace name 'FilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Filters\HandleModelStateExceptionAttribute.cs (14): The type or namespace name 'IExceptionFilter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Filters\SecurityFilter.cs (15): The type or namespace name 'FilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Filters\SecurityFilter.cs (15): The type or namespace name 'IAuthorizationFilter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Framework\base_MembershipProvider.cs (6): The type or namespace name 'WebMatrix' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Framework\base_MembershipProvider.cs (23): The type or namespace name 'ExtendedMembershipProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Filters\AjaxOnly.cs (18): The type or namespace name 'ControllerContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Filters\HandleModelStateExceptionAttribute.cs (20): The type or namespace name 'ExceptionContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Filters\SecurityFilter.cs (25): The type or namespace name 'AuthorizationContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (30): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (29): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (124): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (123): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (213): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (212): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (310): The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 HtmlExtensions\BootStrap3Helpers.cs (309): The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Utils\ModelStateException.cs (52): The type or namespace name 'ModelStateDictionary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 Framework\base_MembershipProvider.cs (322): The type or namespace name 'OAuthAccountData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


WARNINGS ----
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Transactions", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Web", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Transactions", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (983): The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

Comment: Did you enable nuget package restore for the solution?
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore
Right click solution in VS and click "Enable NuGet Package restore"

Comment: I do not see an option for "Enable NuGet Package restore" by right clicking the Solution 'SolutionName' in Visual Studio - Solution Explorer.  I have the latest Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you see a .nuget folder in Visual Studio? It should be at the top.

Comment: I figured out the issue.   MVC 4 had to be installed.  It had the missing assemblies.

Comment: I also installed - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx ONLY the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and rebooted the server and BAMMMMM!!!!!! Builds Zero Errors and Zero Warnings.    Hope this helps others.

Comment: @Moojjoo, Congrat's, why not post it as an answer? :)

Comment: I posted... Thanks Dave...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone for the help.  The following information worked to provide the ASP.NET MVC4 to build correctly on the build server.  **The MAJOR issue was missing asssemblies** -

The following was installed on our build server to correct the issues

- MVC 4 had to be installed on the build server by downloading from - 
  http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4
- Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8 -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx
- **Very important** I copied the directories from my development machine because we are developing with Visual Studio 2013.

  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ (I learned this from other posts on stackoverflow)

    - Web
    - WebApplications
- Added the following build parameters in the PROCESS TAB for the Build Definitions that are sent to MSBUILD

  - /p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions="none" ***Prevents the .pdb and .xml file outputs***
  - /p:IsAutoBuild="True" - ***Add the following to the .csproj***

Add the following to the end of your .csproj or .vbproj to allow for xml transformation for the .webconfig.  You will need to unload the project file.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
<!--<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>-->
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="$(IsAutoBuild)=='True'">
 <ItemGroup>
   <DeleteAfterBuild Include="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.*.config" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.config" />
 <Delete Files="@(DeleteAfterBuild)" />
</Target>
```

- /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 - ***Ensures you are building for VS2013***
- /p:DebugSymbols=false - ***Build kept pushing out only the main project .pdb and this caused it to stop the output.***
- /p:DebugType=None ***Stop DEBUG symbols as well***

Rebooted the server and BAMMMMM!!!!!! Builds Zero Errors and Zero Warnings. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear that you solved the problem, but if you have problems in future I would advise installing visual studio properly on your build server rather than copying bits of your development pcs into it. By taking it piecemeal you could get all kinds of breakages, and won't benefit from things like Windows updates for visual studio (meaning it will be harder to keep your build server in sync with your dev PCs). Over time it is likely that things will get more and more unstable as you try to hobble new versions of your bulld system together.